# Default Security Group in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

When we create a VPC in AWS, a default Security Group is created. It has one Inbound rule in which Source field has reference to Security Group itself.

What does it means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that if you create two EC2 instances with that security group, they can comunicate with each other without any network restrictions.

You can learn more on [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#DefaultSecurityGroup).